# How to define a function for a (somewhat) partially specialized class

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible. Here's an example:

```
template <typename T>
class Ref
{
    void Decrement();
};

template <typename T>
class Collection {};

// This will error
template <>
template <typename T>
void Ref<Collection<T>>::Decrement() {}
```

Comment: Redeclare the class partial specialization first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specialize just one function inside a class template; you have to specialize the class template as a whole.

```
template <typename T>
class Ref
{
    void Decrement();
};

template <typename T>
class Collection {};

template <typename T>
class Ref<Collection<T>> {
    void Decrement() {}
};
```

You *can* specialize a function template inside a class, *i.e.*, this:

```
class Ref {
    template <typename U> void Decrement();
};
```

or a function template inside a class template...

```
template <typename T>
class Ref {
    template <typename U> void Decrement();
};
```

However, even then, a *partial* specialization, which is what you want to do, cannot be done for a function template; function templates can only be fully specialized for individual types, and never partially specialized, whereas class templates can be either partially or fully specialized.

Comment: It's not really a matter of specializing the function though. For example, this will compile fine:

`template <>`
`void Ref<int>::Decrement() {}`

Comment: "fully specialized for individual types, and never partially specialized"

Sorry, I misread that the first time. Thank you.